# Excel with rows of details related to other row

Tags: excel

There is a way to have a group of rows related to other one, in the same sheet, like a more detailed information? Obviously must keep them always next to the main row if you filter or sort.

Desired example based on vehicles and travels:

```
        A            B            C            D 
  1    [ID]    [VEHICLE TYPE]  [BRAND]     [COLOUR]
+ 2   A-171        PICKUP       HONDA        BLACK
- 3               [TRAVEL]       [KM]      [STATION]
- 4              12/08/2016     13.000     BARCELONA
- 5              13/08/2016     13.750      DONOSTI
+ 6   B-501         VAN         RENAULT      WHITE
- 7               [TRAVEL]       [KM]      [STATION]
- 8              12/08/2016    117.800       PARIS
- 9              13/08/2016    120.000     AMSTERDAM
- 10             14/08/2016    124.320       MUNICH
```

So when you sort the spreadsheet, should keep always the travel rows next to the vehicle row.

It is that possible? If not, what can I do to get this or similar? (I don't mind to use other sheet tab, but it wasn't the ideal)

Comment: So you want to sort by several rows at a time (for example, putting rows 6-10 in the same order before rows 2-5)?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I would use the `[ID]` column to help with sorting. For example, put `A-171` for all rows that need to be kept together. You can use `Data` > `Outline` > `Group` but if they are collapsed it won't sort the hidden rows.

Comment: Yes, that's what I need. But apart from the commented by you (won't sort the hidden rows), it doesn't work even if they have the same [ID] and I sort by [VEHICLE TYPE]. In addition, the group is just affecting the row (static), if the data is sorted, the group keeps on the original rows.

Comment: It will only keep the rows together if you sort by `[ID]`. Whatever column you sort on must have a common beginning in each row you want kept together. If you want to sort by `[Vehicle Type]` then maybe put `PU - Pickup`, `PU - [Travel]`, `PU - 12/08/2016`, `PU - 13/08/2016` so that those rows are kept together. I could be wrong but I see no other way of doing it. Grouping is not really a solution for you. I just added that as an FYI.

Comment: Hmm yep that will work but I can't do that.. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Group function (Alt-A-G-G), and they won't be sorted as usual if you use sort on the whole column

Comment: Yup, I tried that before ask but the problem is they can't be sorted. That's why I'm asking if I can get the example above and sort them, keeping consistent the data.